# background work during activity destroy or restart

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have read this in Android developers

> Caution: Another problem you might encounter when using a worker
>   thread is unexpected restarts in your activity due to a runtime
>   configuration change (such as when the user changes the screen
>   orientation), which may destroy your worker thread. To see how you can
>   persist your task during one of these restarts and how to properly
>   cancel the task when the activity is destroyed, see the source code
>   for the Shelves sample application.

I couldn't clearly understand from the provided [code](https://code.google.com/p/shelves/)

When I have a background work which is tied to Ui thread and thus can be stopped during `configuration change` -

how to properly handle worker thread during `restart` vs `destroy` ?

Comment: If you need something long-lasting in background, consider using Service. If what you do has direct relation to asynchronously loading contents for Activity to show, design thread so it could finish without deadlock and forget about it.

Comment: Could you post reference to the Shalves sample application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your background work is tied to an `Activity`, you should use `AsyncTask` which provides a `cancel` method. From within the task you can check the `isCancelled` to know whether to exit the operation. When the activity is created again by Android, you will have the opportunity to start the task again.

If your background work is not tied to any particular activity or UI element, you should use an `IntentService` and run the service from anywhere in your app. Then the background work will not be interrupted by an orientation change.

A quick fix/hack sometimes used is to configure Android not to recreate your activity when the orientation changes - you can do this with the `android:configChanges` element of your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Caution.  Do not use `android:configChanges` unless you *really* understand what you are doing.  It's a perfect way to hide bugs in your life cycle handling since it can only deal with a subset of all the ways in which your activities can be recreated.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I referred to it as a hack. Probably shouldnt have mentioned it at all.